# Can I sleep/hibernate the PC from a windows store app?

Tags: hibernate, windows-store-apps, sleep

I just want to make a button to sleep the PC:

```
<Button Clicked="Button_Clicked">Sleep</Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows store apps are using WinRT , and WinRT does not support actions like Sleeping / Restarting etc.

Simply , you can't.